# Get int array values from int bit base 2 value

Tags: java

I have bit representation like below

```
Bit 0(2^0 .= 1) - 1
Bit 1(2^1 .= 2) - 2
Bit 2(2^2 .= 4) - 4
Bit 3(2^3 .= 8) - 8
Bit 4(2^4 .= 16) - 16
```

A value of `7` means we have `1+2+4`. But how do i get this array programmatically?

Comment: Could uou, please, add some *examples*, e.g. if in case of `7` input do you want `1+2+4` output?

Comment: What have you tried so far and didn't work for you? Show us some of your code

Comment: Are you asking for a program that output the 'base 2' (binary) representation of an integer?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko for example value 7 should give me an array of [1,2,4], 6 - [2,4], 4 - [4], 3 - [1,2].

Comment: @VirgileD i am not sure what that means, but check below for what i want to achieve.

7 should give me an array of [1,2,4], 
6 should give me an array of [2,4], 
5 should give me an array of [1,4], 
4 should give me an array of [4], 
3 should give me an array of [1,2].

etc

Answer (score 1):

Continuosly divide by 2 and save the remainder

```
int n = 7;
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
while(n>0) {
    sb.append(n%2);
    n = n/2;
}
System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
```

You can store it anyway you want. Currently it is stored as string (Binary Representation of 7).

To convert back from  the string to binary, start from LSB and add by powers of 2 of the bit position if the bit value is 1

Comment: your solution is giving me an output of 111

Comment: bcoz it is the binary rep of 7. To get the rep run a loop and mutiply by powers of 2. i.e  7 = 1*2^2 +1*2^1 + 1*2^0
gor 6 u will get 110 which translates to 6 = 1*2^2 +1*2^1 + 0*2^0

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic, works up to intmax (Very easy to change to max long by just changing type :))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int originalInt = 127;
    toIntegerArray(originalInt);
}

private static List<Integer> toIntegerArray(int originalInt) {
    String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(originalInt);

    // Reversed, for easier logic when building string
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(bits).reverse();

    char[] bitArray = s.toString().toCharArray();

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.length; i++) {
        if (bitArray[i] == '1') {
            result.add((int) Math.pow(2, i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Original int: " + originalInt);
    System.out.println("Bit pattern: " + bits);
    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This gives the binary representation not the intended output i want

Comment: @FelixKirathe, with input 127 you get [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64], the format you specified in a comment. Can you specify in your question what format you want then, the printouts are for showing what is going on, feel free to remove printouts if not needed.

Comment: @FelixKirathe If you copy paste the code into your editor, you should be able to verify that this is Java...

Comment: sorry for that. Its java code and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, i am looking for c# code which is not resource intensive like what you have.

Comment: Maybe you should not tag it as Java if you want C#. And the question does not specify anything about performance.

Comment: And maybe accept one of the answers and ask a new question specifically about the performance requirements? And please then include what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you, i will do so now.

Answer (score 0):

I got below working, but for values below 31. Any suggestion on how to allow any value?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", log3(100)));   
    }

    static int[] log3(int x) {
        List<int> pow = new List<int>();

        int val=x;

        do{
           if(x>= 1 << val){
                if(1<<val>0){
                    pow.Add(1<<val);
                }
                x-=1<<val;
            }
            val-=1;
        }while(val>=0);

        return pow.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive streaming option:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Class {
  private static IntStream intToBinaryParts(final int input, final int count) {
    int powerOf2 = (int) Math.pow(2, count);
    if (count < 0) {
      return IntStream.empty();
    } else if (input < powerOf2) {
      return intToBinaryParts(input, count - 1);
    } else {
      return IntStream.concat(intToBinaryParts(input - powerOf2, count - 1), IntStream.of(powerOf2));
    }
  }

  public static List<Integer> intToBinaryParts(final int input) {
    return intToBinaryParts(input, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(input) / Math.log(2)))
      .mapToObj(Integer::new)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(intToBinaryParts(7));
    System.out.println(intToBinaryParts(8));
    System.out.println(intToBinaryParts(100));
    System.out.println(intToBinaryParts(1234567890));
  }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly for java. Can we have one for c#?